# Is it worth having a resize method in a LibGDX mobile application?

Tags: libgdx

From what I have read, the resize method in LibGDX is meant to resize the viewport and center the camera if the window is resized. Since a mobile application cannot be resized, is it worth including it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes required even in mobile application too.

1. If your app is for both landscape and portrait mode then you need do your stuff like changing layout of your UI in `resize()` method.
2. `resize()` method of `ApplicationListener` is called after `create()`. Your viewport need to be scaled according to your device screen width/height and also what's the choice of your viewport.

Comment: My app is portrait-only mode and my viewport is a StretchViewport

Comment: @vladutelu you can skip overriding `resize()` method, if your game if for particular orientation mode but I prefer to update viewport by `screenwidth` and `screenheight` by overriding `resize()` method. LibGDX is cross platform game development framework and desktop is not only for testing purpose (some game is for only desktop) so go with the flow.

Answer (score 2):

It is not, I have never used the resize method in mobile games.

To be honest I don't even use it on desktop games and they work just as intended when the window is resized.